# Can I address the recipient again in the body of a formal letter?

Tags: letter

I start a formal letter like this:

> Dear Sir/Madam, ...

May I again address the person I am writing to somewhere in the body of the letter?

I see many people addressing the recipient more than once in a letter.

Is it valid?

Comment: I'm not sure in what context you'd need that - usually, sure, you can - by using 'you'.

Comment: Sales agents tend to use this incredibly creepy pattern where they keep repeatedly addressing you by your name; it's a thing they are trained to do. I find it incredibly creepy, and it's a quick way to loose my trust and interest in anything they are pushing. Have you seen it in this kind of a pattern? Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

I will explain this by typing out an example email:

> Dear, user100323
>
> I am emailing you regarding an account transfer from my account to account number XXXX. "So user100323", Can you help me out?
>
> Thanks,
>
> Joseph Casey

That you can do.